# With a rolling pawn, how can I have a component that follows its rotation, but stays upright and only rolls?

Tags: rotation, unreal-4

I'm using the UE4 rolling pawn to create a [Metroid Prime morph ball](https://youtu.be/Vb4mDi6PApM?t=234) style pawn. I've got it set up with a ribbon particle component on a spring arm, inheriting yaw, but if I set it to inherit roll, the axes invert and cause the particle emitter to flip and break the ribbon trail.

I'm sure there's some kind of rotation math that it needs, but it's beyond me. I've tried doing various math things to the axes, but I haven't been able to get it to click at all.

Comment: I think this question may get some more feedback if you provide us with some more details, such as any scripts/blueprints you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by using "get actor right vector" on the pawn, then "make rot from x", then applying that rotator to the particle component with "set world rotation".